# How would you implement this tutorial screen in Android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, fragment

I saw this when I first started and opened my emulator and wanted to include something like in my application.[image]

Does anyone know how you implement this tutorial? Do  you basically have a layout file with a TextView, ImageView, and a Button? And inflate it with some kind of dialog fragment? Is there a way to account for the transparency as well?

I experimented with a dialog fragment but mine looks nothing like the screenshot above. (no transparency, position at center, etc...)

[image]

Comment: You can implement that view as a Layout with colour black half translucid (transparent), in Hexadecimal 80 in the most significative bytes.

Comment: Can you refer me to the right attribute to use, i don't what you mean by half translucid

Comment: Well, You can assign a color, don't you? A color is usually coded with 6 hexadecimal digits, then there are other 2 most significative which code the transparency, 0x80 codes halb transparency, or 50%, the attribute is "background", in xml File android:background=#80000000, programmatically setBackGroundColor or something like this for halb transparent black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used it so I can not give you a code example. However it is documented in the [Help Section](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/help.html) of the developer documentation.

[This library can help you too](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView).

Comment: And i was thinking to check if the user was using this app the first time, i should just use shared preferences