# How to resolve theme has no action bar error, make it so options menu is highlighted?

Tags: android, android-layout, github, android-actionbar, android-menu

This is based off my last question - 
[How would you implement this tutorial screen in Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472480/how-would-you-implement-this-tutorial-screen-in-android-app)

I went and looked over the ReadMe for the github project the person recommended - 
https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/README.md

I followed the instructions and added the github project as a depenency and copied this code to test

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
.setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.OVERFLOW))
.setContentTitle("ShowcaseView")
.setContentText("This is highlighting the Home button")
.hideOnTouchOutside()
.build();
```

the ShowcaseView stuff in my application.

However when I ran the application, here's the error I got 
[image]

Here is my code for generating the options menu

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

and R.menu.menu_main

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.chris.myapplication.MainActivity">
<item
    android:title="Settings"
    />
</menu>
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this or change the ReadMe client code so that the ShowCaseView  highlights the options menu(way of telling user what menu options there are)? I tried digging through the source files of this project but it was too time consuming to comment/understand everything and I couldn't find anything regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue has being answered here:: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/issues/251  and here:: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/issues/203

Comment: yeah thanks for your link. For using an api like this, do you actually have to go into the source code or just the ReadMe is fine?

Comment: It's a good practice exploring the library you want to use first if that's your question. If you encounter issues in the cause of using the library then checking the library's issue archive is the next best solution.

Comment: yeah in terms of that library, its just hard to understand everything and go in order.